# Text to speech Android app failing to work

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have recently downloaded an Android app for text to speech and successfully imported it to Android Studio. But it fails to work. When I enter some text and click on the Speak Out button I have no result in my headphones. I find this very surprising as my headphones' speakers and mic are working fine with Skype.

Comment: Please share more information about your problem. Which app is that? Which version of Android you are running? I think it's improbable the problem is happening on Android Studio side

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This Text to speech sample app I have downloaded from Androidhive.info. Actually I had a tough time finding the android platform for this app. As I am not sure if this is visible somewhere in the code. Finally in project structure I was able to find - Compile SDK version as API8: Android 2.2 (Froyo). I am quite new to Android Studio. I am experimenting with samples to get used to it. Build Tools Version is 25.0.0. Please help. Gradle version is 2.14.1 and Android plugin version is 2.2.0.